# How to resolve problem with "lifecycle" in Minio?

Tags: amazon-s3, devops, minio

Good afternoon, I have such a problem, I have s3 miniO, and there are buckets in it, I would like to be able to set up lifecycle in buckets, but the button is not active in the web interface, although through the mc console, I can create all the rules, please tell me in what could be the problem

version

2021-11-24T23:19:33Z
[image: MiniO web]

I tried to read docs, and find answers in stack but couldn't do it

Answer (score 0):

This is governed by policy based access control. what policy is attached to the user accessing this page? you can read more about policies here: https://min.io/docs/minio/kubernetes/upstream/administration/identity-access-management/policy-based-access-control.html#minio-policy-actions